# JavaScript/Jquery Problema con ajax que devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-mobile

tengo un ajax que me trae de mi bd el dato de un precio, y mi problema esta en devolver el dato, que cuando llamo a mi metodo(en el cual tengo el ajax) me lo devuelve como undefined, y no se porque..

En mi ajax hago console log, para ver si el problema es que no se conecta bien con mi backend, pero no, se conecta bien y me da el resultado esperado, pero creo que no lo estoy devolviendo bien...

```js
//Traigo el precio del articulo dependiendo del interno
function ObtengoPrecioXInterno(interno) {
    var dir = "DoyPrecioPoscomm";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: api + dir + "?interno=" + interno,
        success: function(ret) {
            var precio = ret;
            console.log(precio);
            //hasta aca funciona bien, en consola me aparece el precio, pero me falta algo mas?
            //probe con colocar Return precio; pero no funciona
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}




$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#sugerencias_articulos", function() {
    var interno = $(".imgDada").attr("data-Interno");
    console.log(interno);
    //este es el interno que quiero ponerle como parametro a mi metodo ajax
    //el console me da bien, me devuelve el interno bien!!
    console.log(ObtengoPrecioXInterno(interno));
    // me devuelve undefined
    var precio = ObtengoPrecioXInterno(interno);
    console.log(precio);
    //y aca tambien
    //Me parece que mi problema esta, en donde guardo mi dato en el ajax, no logro traer el dato correctamente
```

Comment: agrega el `dataType: " "` abajo del `url` y comenta que sucede.

Comment: Me sigue dando igual

Answer (score 2):

El problema recide en el asincronismo del llamado Ajax. Por defecto todas las llamadas ajax son asincronas, es decir, no puedes esperar un valor de retorno de la función que hace la invocación Ajax.

Para resolverlo, veo 3 alternativas:

a) Hacer que el llamado Ajax sea sincrono (No recomendado, porque perdería el sentido de ser ajax)

b) Colocar la lógica dentro del 'success' de la invocación ajax:

```
        success: function(ret) {
        var precio = ret;
        console.log(precio);
     //Pon aqui tu lógica
    },
```

c) hacer que la función ObtengoPrecioXInterno reciba un parametro de tipo función (callback) para que lo invoques cuando ocurra el 'success':

```
function ObtengoPrecioXInterno(interno, callback) {
var dir = "DoyPrecioPoscomm";
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: api + dir + "?interno=" + interno,
    success: function(ret) {
        var precio = ret;
        console.log(precio);
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(precio)
         }

    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Es que no hay mas logica que eso, yo quiero que me devuelva el precio(que por console lo muestra) pero cuando lo llamo me da undefined

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, probe con tu alternativa c pero de todas formas me sigue dando undefined

Comment: Bueno, es que debes tener muy en cuenta el tema de asincronismo. No es posible esperar un valor de retorno de una función cuando este valor de retorno dependa de un llamado ajax, salvo que se configure el llamado ajax como sincrono (Como lo comenté anteriormente, es poco recomendable): https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ colocando async = false. Te recomiendo leer este artículo https://carlosazaustre.es/manejando-la-asincronia-en-javascript/